# Filter by TO_CHAR() in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, to-char

I'm running into some unexpected behavior, which doesn't make any sense to me.

I have a table with a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column.

If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(ssef.SS_TIMESTAMP, 'DAY') FROM SS_EDGE_FORECAST ssef
```

I get the following results:

```
FRIDAY
TUESDAY
SUNDAY
SATURDAY
MONDAY
THURSDAY
```

So far so good.

However, if I try to filter my query results by specifying a specific weekday in the `WHERE` clause, I get no results:

```
SELECT * FROM SS_EDGE_FORECAST ssef
WHERE TO_CHAR(ssef.SS_TIMESTAMP, 'DAY') = 'MONDAY'
```

[image]

This appears to be a direct contradiction.
Why would the `TO_CHAR` operation produce the correct results in the `SELECT` clause, but not in the `WHERE` clause?
Why would I be able to select something, but ***NOT*** be able to *filter* based on that same item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is, that TO_CHAR(x,'DAY') is for Monday returning 'Monday   ' with blanks in the end. According to documentation for TO_CHAR function:

> The character elements MONTH, MON, DAY, and DY are padded with
>   trailing blanks to the width of the longest full month name, the
>   longest abbreviated month name, the longest full date name...

The correct result shall be returned if you do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM SS_EDGE_FORECAST ssef WHERE TO_CHAR(ssef.SS_TIMESTAMP, 'DAY') like 'MONDAY%'
```

Or even better, the TO_CHAR function has so-called format model modifiers, which you can use for removing these trailing blanks:

```
SELECT * FROM SS_EDGE_FORECAST ssef WHERE TO_CHAR(ssef.SS_TIMESTAMP, 'fmDAY') = 'MONDAY'
```

shall return desired output.

Documentation for TO_CHAR and format model modifiers here:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1
WHERE  TRIM(TO_CHAR(ABC,'DAY'))  = 'MONDAY'
```

Trim function is added.

The reason is:

TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP,'DAY') will return 9 character string. Apparently, there are 3 trailing blank spaces at the end of 'Monday'

Here is the test case:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=653f8f9afee72448b82ae1b80743458a)

Answer (score 1):

Its a whitespace / trimming issue.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY') FROM dual ssef where TRIM(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY'))='TUESDAY';
```